# Android - Play (mp3) from memory while streaming

Tags: java, android, audio, stream, mp3

Sorry about the weird title, I couldn't think of anything better.
In my Android App I want to stream an .mp3 file from an http server, which requires basic authentication. The task is to download the data and save it to the sdcard while playing. (Basicly streaming an mp3 from an http server but also saving the file)

I managed to download the mp3 from the server to the sdcard and to play the downloaded file with the Android MediaPlayer class. But playing only works right when the file is downloaded completely. I want my App to play WHILE downloading.

Can someone point out a good solution to this problem? I thought about using some third-party audio library to stream mp3 audio from memory but I couldn't find anything useful for my problem. Are there any good free librarys for Android that suit my needs?